# Siebel - changing the DB name

Tags: siebel

We have a Siebel version 8.1.1. and we need to change the DB name to something else. 
can you please help me to identify as to where in the Seibel server I need to make the changes to reflect the new DB name? Is there a particular config file that I need to change? The Database server and port are not going to change, only the name of the database will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This reply is a bit late but...

Above answers are about Datasource. Datasource has parameters to create connection with DB like host name, user id and psw. Database name should be part of Datasource.
For example:
- Oracle has SID in tnsnames.ora file
- Microsoft database name can be changed in ODBC Data Source Administrator

So it debends what kind of db software you use. For future I would like to suggest to use My Oracle Support Community (MOSC) because Siebel developer community is much more active there than here.

Answer (score 0):

This information is clearly documented in Oracle bookshelf for Siebel. There should be a profile configuration for your Datasource.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the DB is gone. So I can access the Siebel. However the siebel app server is still good. So what configuration files I need to change to point it to the new database?

Answer (score 0):

```
change param datasource=<data_source_name> for compdef <object_manager_name>
```